Why is the animation of the plane not being rendered as the uTime is being altered as the elapsed time is changed everyframe?
I am trying to create a flag like animation by constructing a vertex shader that takes inputs of uFrequency and uTime. I got the vertexshader right but the animation while change in seconds isn't being rendered.
flag component:

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import portalVertexShader from "../shaders/vertex.glsl"
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber';
import { Plane } from '@react-three/drei';


export default function Flag() {
    const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
    const materialRef = useRef();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const startTime = new Date();
  
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        const currentTime = new Date();
        const elapsed = currentTime - startTime;
        setElapsedTime(elapsed);
      }, 1000); // Update every second
  
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }, []); // Run only once when the component mounts
  
    // Convert milliseconds to seconds for easier reading
    const seconds = elapsedTime / 1000;
  
    // Ensure the materialRef has been initialized
    useFrame(() => {
      
        materialRef.current.uniforms.uTime.value = seconds;
        console.log(materialRef.current.uniforms.uTime.value)
      }
    ); 
  return (
    <Plane args={[1, 1,32, 32]} rotation={[1.5,0,0]}>
      <shaderMaterial 
       ref={materialRef}
        side={THREE.DoubleSide}
       uniforms={
        {
          uTime:{value:0},
          uFrequency: { value: new THREE.Vector2(10, 20) } // Converted to vec2
        }
      } vertexShader={portalVertexShader} />
      </Plane>
  )
}


vertexshader:

uniform vec2 uFrequency;
uniform float uTime;

void main()

{
   

    vec4 modelPosition= modelMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);

    modelPosition.z+=sin(modelPosition.x*uFrequency.x - uTime * 3.0 )*0.1;


    vec4 viewPosition= viewMatrix * modelPosition;
    vec4 projectedPosition= projectionMatrix * viewPosition;

        gl_Position=projectedPosition;
       

}

I tried creating a jsx syntax for the shader material like this :
const PortalMaterial = shaderMaterial(
    {
        uTime: 0,
        uColorStart: new THREE.Color('#ffffff'),
        uColorEnd: new THREE.Color('#000000')
    },
    portalVertexShader,
    portalFragmentShader
)

extend({ PortalMaterial })

and I used it in the component material, but all i get is : TypeError: Class constructor material cannot be invoked without 'new'

You have data flow problems.
const seconds = elapsedTime / 1000;

This line of code assumes that your components is going to get re-rendered multiple times to recalculate the seconds variable based on the elapsedTime.
You should avoid that. Instead, you might want to pick the elapsedTime from the built-in useFrame hook:
  useFrame((state) => {
    const { elapsedTime } = state.clock;
    materialRef.current.uniforms.uTime.value = elapsedTime ;
  });

With that tweak, you should be ready to go
